# "Which one to choose? Lemmatization or Stemming?"

Tags: text, nlp, normalization, kaggle

To perform NLP tasks, like "**Predict which Tweets are about real disasters and which ones are not**" from KAGGLE, link: https://www.kaggle.com/c/nlp-getting-started

Which task should I perform to normalize my texts, Lemmatization or stemming?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want to do.

Lemmatisation is linguistically motivated, and generally more reliable to give a correct result when reducing an inflected word to its base form. However, it is more resource intensive.

Stemming is (usually) a short procedure which uses string matching to remove parts of a string. This is much faster, doesn't need a lexicon, but the results aren't as accurate.

There is also a difference in output: Lemmatisation preserves the base class, so *revolved* is changed into *revolve*, and *revolution* remains unchanged (it is already the base form). In some stemming algorithms, derivational suffixes (-*tion*) are also removed, so all of the above might end up as *revol*. This might be what you want, as it returns something like a 'stem', or base morpheme.